# Proving Hilbert transform is skew-adjoint

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-transforms, singular-integrals

I want to solve the following exercise from [Ioannis Parissis's lecture notes](https://yannisparissis.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/dmat0101-notes-6-introduction-to-singular-integral-operators-the-hilbert-transform/) (corollary 5)

> The Hilbert transform, $H$, defined for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as
>   $$\widehat{Hf}(\xi) = -i \: \text{sgn}(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi) $$
>   is skew-adjoint, i.e. for $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}Hf(x)\overline{g(x)}dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\overline{Hg(x)}dx$$

But have no idea how to approach this problem. How can Fourier transform be used with integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle f,g \rangle_{L^2} = \langle \hat{f}, \hat{g} \rangle_{L^2}$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know why this is true. Can you tell where I can find its proof?

Comment: Any intro fourier analysis book. (You might recognize this statement as "the fourier transform is an isometry on $L^2$" or as "Parseval's Identity").

Comment: But, Parvesal identity gives relation between Fourier coefficients and Fourier transform is an isometry since $||\hat{f}||_2 = ||f||_2$ (Plancheral). What I am confused with is, how can we extend this to the inner product of two different functions?

Comment: OOPS. I meant plancheral. Any norm preserving linear map preserves inner products. Look up "polarization identity"

Comment: Yes, I recall I read about polarization identity from my functional analysis course: "If $||.||$ norm on a complex vector space satisfies parallelogram law then polarization identity gives the inner product." So, since $L^2$ is an inner product space, isometry extends to inner product space?

Comment: I dont understand your question. The point is, the polarization identity expresses the inner product just in terms of norms. So if something preserves norms, it preserves inner products. Thus, Plancherel implies my answer. [I might add that the way I've seen Plancherel proven is by first establishing that it preserves inner products, so using polarization identity might be circular reasoning]

Comment: The identity should be $$\left \langle f, g \right \rangle_{L^2 (\mathbb T)} = \left \langle \hat f, \widehat g \right \rangle_{\ell^2 (\mathbb Z)}.$$

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa No. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can't we think of $\hat f$ as a sequence in $\ell^2 (\mathbb Z)\ $? This is what is written in Grafakos' book.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa No; note that $f$ is not even a function defined on the torus $\mathbb{T}$. For every (maybe, locally compact Abelian) group $G$, you have the fourier transform (of a function defined on $G$) defined on the dual group $\widehat{G}$. In the case of the torus $G = \mathbb{T}$, the dual group is $\widehat{\mathbb{T}} = \mathbb{Z}$. For the case of the reals $G = \mathbb{R}$, the dual group is $\widehat{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}$. The question in the OP asks about functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and the Hilbert transform is defined on such functions. Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: @mathworker21$:$ Thanks for your clarification. I am only working with functions defined on $\mathbb T$ i.e. $2\pi$-periodic functions defined on $\mathbb R.$ I am not familiar with the abstract version of it yet. Could you please refer a book that describes all sorts of stuffs? I would like to know this abstraction. BTW what is the dual of locally compact group?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa To be honest, I have barely studied the general group fourier transform setting and just know the fourier transform for several specific groups. If you want the general theory, maybe Rudin's "fourier analysis on groups"?